# 404 Errors with URL Appended "%7B%7BiframeSrc%7D%7D"?

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

Website has had no changes for about a year, but this new error has started to appear.

In the Web Console (FireFox), not sure if relevant:

```
verify.js: plugin added.  verify.notify.min.js:5:14154
["add",{"textareas":[],"contenteditables":[],"iframes":[],"htmlghosts":[]}]  bundle.js:8321:29
```

The page actually loads but seems to call the 404 page which automatically sends an email to the webmaster with the appended text, "%7B%7BiframeSrc%7D%7D". The 404 page is not displayed.

Anybody any ideas, or what to check?

Thanks.

Comment: I just saw the same thing on my wordpress website... first time, no updates or changes here either. I'm using the 'Shareaholic' plugin for social media sharing, and that seems to inject a couple of iframes. Something may have changed on their side. And I'd actually love to get rid of that plugin, feels a bit too invasive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@maxdownunder you are quite correct, it's a new feature by Shareaholic, "Badge", which can be disabled in Settings. Thank you for that nugget.